# SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler : Unexpected exception occurred invoking async method during kafka junit tests

Tags: spring, docker, junit, apache-kafka, docker-compose

Scenario: I want to test my kafka producer against a Kafka Docker Container instead of KafkaEmbedded.

Goal: I want to start kafka container from my docker-compose before executing a simple producer test.

Searching around I found a plugin that can run docker-compose ( [docker-compose-rule](https://github.com/palantir/docker-compose-rule)) and I am following its guidance.

My straight question: does this exception give a clue what is going wrong

```
2020-03-04 18:14:39.420  INFO 15372 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskExecutor'
2020-03-04 18:14:39.421  INFO 15372 --- [extShutdownHook] o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 30000 ms.
2020-03-04 18:14:39.428 ERROR 15372 --- [kaMsgExecutor-2] .a.i.SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler : Unexpected exception occurred invoking async method: public void com.arquiteturareferencia.kafkaassyncsend.producer.Producer.send(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InterruptException: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:937) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
```

Surrounding doubt: I read from this logs firstly "Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskExecutor'" then "Closing the Kafka producer" and finally "[kaMsgExecutor-2] .a.i.SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler". Does it mean the root cause is either ExecutorService or kafka producer isn't available at the moment of test? If so, what I have to settup in other to make it available while running the test?

Here is my Junit test:

```
import org.junit.ClassRule;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import com.arquiteturareferencia.kafkaassyncsend.producer.Producer;
import com.palantir.docker.compose.DockerComposeRule;
import com.palantir.docker.compose.connection.waiting.HealthChecks;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
class KafkaAssyncSendApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private Producer p;

    @ClassRule
    public static DockerComposeRule docker = DockerComposeRule.builder()
        .file("src/test/resources/docker-compose.yml")
        .waitingForService("kafka", HealthChecks.toHaveAllPortsOpen())
        .build();

    @Test
    public void testSend() throws Exception {
        p.send("test", "Messagem demonstrativa assincrona 2");
    }
}
```

My producer config

```
@EnableAsync
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaProducerConfig.class);

    @Value("${kafka.brokers}")
    private String servers;

    @Bean
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("KafkaMsgExecutor-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, servers);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        return props;
    }

}
```

Producer:

```
@Service
public class Producer {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Producer.class);

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    @Async
    public void send(String topic, String message) {
        ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(topic, message);
        future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, String>>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final SendResult<String, String> message) {
                LOGGER.info("sent message= " + message + " with offset= " + message.getRecordMetadata().offset());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(final Throwable throwable) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

My docker-compose.yml in case it matters

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENERS:
        "INTERNAL://kafka:9090,\
         EXTERNAL://:9092"
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS:
        "INTERNAL://kafka:9090,\
         EXTERNAL://192.168.99.100:9092"
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP:
        "INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,\
         EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT"
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
```

Full Exception logs while testing:

```
2020-03-04 18:14:28.132  INFO 15372 --- [           main] c.a.k.KafkaAssyncSendApplicationTests    : Starting KafkaAssyncSendApplicationTests on SPANOT149 with PID 15372 (started by Cast in C:\WSs\pockafka\kafka-assync-send)
2020-03-04 18:14:28.135  INFO 15372 --- [           main] c.a.k.KafkaAssyncSendApplicationTests    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-03-04 18:14:29.072  INFO 15372 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService
2020-03-04 18:14:29.089  INFO 15372 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'taskExecutor'
2020-03-04 18:14:29.281  INFO 15372 --- [           main] c.a.k.KafkaAssyncSendApplicationTests    : Started KafkaAssyncSendApplicationTests in 1.424 seconds (JVM running for 3.408)
2020-03-04 18:14:29.339  INFO 15372 --- [kaMsgExecutor-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.ProducerConfig    : ProducerConfig values: 
    acks = 1
    batch.size = 16384
    bootstrap.servers = [192.168.99.100:9092]
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    client.dns.lookup = default
    client.id = 
    compression.type = none
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    delivery.timeout.ms = 120000
    enable.idempotence = false
    interceptor.classes = []
    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
    linger.ms = 0
    max.block.ms = 60000
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
    max.request.size = 1048576
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retries = 2147483647
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
    transactional.id = null
    value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

2020-03-04 18:14:29.527  INFO 15372 --- [kaMsgExecutor-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 2.3.1
2020-03-04 18:14:29.529  INFO 15372 --- [kaMsgExecutor-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: 18a913733fb71c01
2020-03-04 18:14:29.529  INFO 15372 --- [kaMsgExecutor-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1583356469521
2020-03-04 18:14:39.420  INFO 15372 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskExecutor'
2020-03-04 18:14:39.421  INFO 15372 --- [extShutdownHook] o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 30000 ms.
2020-03-04 18:14:39.428 ERROR 15372 --- [kaMsgExecutor-2] .a.i.SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler : Unexpected exception occurred invoking async method: public void com.arquiteturareferencia.kafkaassyncsend.producer.Producer.send(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InterruptException: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:937) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:856) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory$CloseSafeProducer.send(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:592) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:404) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:216) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at com.arquiteturareferencia.kafkaassyncsend.producer.Producer.send(Producer.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.arquiteturareferencia.kafkaassyncsend.producer.Producer$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$78adf947.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:769) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: null
    at java.base/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.SystemTime.waitObject(SystemTime.java:60) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerMetadata.awaitUpdate(ProducerMetadata.java:97) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.waitOnMetadata(KafkaProducer.java:999) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:876) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    ... 15 common frames omitted

2020-03-04 18:14:39.428 ERROR 15372 --- [kaMsgExecutor-1] .a.i.SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler : Unexpected exception occurred invoking async method: public void com.arquiteturareferencia.kafkaassyncsend.producer.Producer.send(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InterruptException: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:937) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:856) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory$CloseSafeProducer.send(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:592) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:404) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:216) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at com.arquiteturareferencia.kafkaassyncsend.producer.Producer.send(Producer.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.arquiteturareferencia.kafkaassyncsend.producer.Producer$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$78adf947.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:769) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: null
    at java.base/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.SystemTime.waitObject(SystemTime.java:60) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerMetadata.awaitUpdate(ProducerMetadata.java:97) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.waitOnMetadata(KafkaProducer.java:999) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:876) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
```